# Make the Javascript includes() method return items with hyphen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, search

I am using the javascript `includes()` method to filter an array of object that looks like this;

```
  const names = [
    {name: 'Rose-mary Thompson', age: 30},
    {name: 'Rose mary Samuel', age: 30},
    {name: 'John-Doe Jackson', age: 30},
    {name: 'John Doe Philips', age: 30},
  ]
```

if I search for 'Rose mary', I want the result to also include 'Rose-mary'.
I don't want the user to have to type hyphen(-) before the names with - come out in the search result.

This is my code;

```
let searchQuery = 'Rose mary'
let filteredResults = []

const searchItems = () => {
    if (searchQuery.length > 1) {
        const results = names.filter((name) => {
            return name.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase());
          });
        filteredResults = results
    }  
}
```

Please how do I achieve this?

Comment: What if you search for `Rose-mary`, do you want to search for `Rose mary` as well ?

Comment: @CodeManiac thank you. The question has already been answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`includes` will only find an **exact** match. Since you're already adjusting each string as you search, you could "normalize" both `searchQuery` and `name` to be lower case with `-` converted to space:

```
const searchItems = () => {
    if (searchQuery.length > 1) {
        const adjustedQuery = searchQuery.toLowerCase().replace(/-/g, " ");
        const results = names.filter((name) => {
            return name.name
                .toLowerCase()
                .replace(/-/g, " ")
                .includes(adjustedQuery);
        });
        filteredResults = results;
    }
};
```

```js
const names = [
    { name: "Rose-mary Thompson", age: 30 },
    { name: "Rose mary Samuel", age: 30 },
    { name: "John-Doe Jackson", age: 30 },
    { name: "John Doe Philips", age: 30 },
];

let searchQuery = "Rose mary";
let filteredResults = [];

const searchItems = () => {
    if (searchQuery.length > 1) {
        const adjustedQuery = searchQuery.toLowerCase().replace(/-/g, " ");
        const results = names.filter((name) => {
            return name.name
                .toLowerCase()
                .replace(/-/g, " ")
                .includes(adjustedQuery);
        });
        filteredResults = results;
    }
};

searchItems();
console.log(filteredResults);
```

---

Side note: I'd also make `names` and `searchQuery` *parameters* to the function, and have it return the results:

```js
const names = [
    { name: "Rose-mary Thompson", age: 30 },
    { name: "Rose mary Samuel", age: 30 },
    { name: "John-Doe Jackson", age: 30 },
    { name: "John Doe Philips", age: 30 },
];

const searchItems = (names, searchQuery) => {
    if (searchQuery.length > 1) {
        const adjustedQuery = searchQuery.toLowerCase().replace(/-/g, " ");
        const results = names.filter((name) => {
            return name.name
                .toLowerCase()
                .replace(/-/g, " ")
                .includes(adjustedQuery);
        });
        return results;
    }
    return names; // Or whatever you want when there's no query
};

console.log(searchItems(names, "Rose mary"));
```